# I did FFT(Fast Fourier Transform), but i can't understand...(python)

Tags: python, numpy, fft, frequency-analysis, acceleration

I got a acceleration data from rotating machine on field. so, I want to know about frequency components. so, did FFT on python (np.fft.fft).

Q) When i got a acceleration data that scale is -20~20 m/s^2. but, after fft, scale was converted 0~1(unit: i don't know....)

I want to understand Why scale was converted after FFT? and How can I set a unit that after FFT?

```
Fs = 51200                             
T = 1/Fs  
L = len(data1)         
t = np.arange(0,L-1)*T      
Y = np.fft.fft(data1)
P2 = abs(Y/L)
P1 = P2[0:int(L/2+1)]
P1[1:-1] = 2*P1[1:-1]
f = Fs*np.arange(0,L/2+1)/L
```

**Before FFT(Original Acceleration data)**
[image: Before FFT, Original Acceleration data]

**After FFT(Don't know abscissa's unit)**
[image: After FFT, Don't know abscissa's unit]

Comment: the x axis units of any fft is frequency (wave cycles per time period). 
the y axis units are the magnitude portion of that frequency within your signal.
i suggest you do some reading about [control theory] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory) and [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Y axis is magnitude, right. but, I want to know magnitude's unit.
when i read some paper, expressed the units of the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform is decomposing your signal in harmonic waves (linear combination of sines and cosines), watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ds0cmAV-Yek) if you need more details.

The FFT will put, for `i in range(-(N+1)//2, N//2)`  at the index `i` the coefficient of a complex exponential of frequency `i * N / Fs`, so the abscissa of your plot is Frequency.